# adding uers to groups in sharepoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to add a user to a sharepoint group based on data from a csv file. I hope that the code marked in **bold** might be the error.

1.User x=web.Ensureuser("domain\logonname") function-->  shows the following error when tried to print any of its file like (x.Title, x.email) --> "The fiels is not assigned" error.
2.Execytequery()--> "The given key is not fount in the dictionary" error.

Please help me with this.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dtErrors = new DataTable();
        dtErrors.Columns.Add("Links");
        dtErrors.Columns.Add("Message");
        DataRow drOutputError = dtErrors.NewRow();
        DataTable dtCsv = csvToDataTable(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString(), true);
        string url = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow drCSV in dtCsv.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    url = drCSV[0].ToString();
                    string grpName = drCSV[1].ToString();
                    string users = drCSV[2].ToString();
                    string[] users1 = users.Split(';');
                    Console.WriteLine("URL picked from CSV: " + url);
                    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
                    {
                        Web web = context.Web;
                        GroupCollection groupColl = web.SiteGroups;
                        context.Load(groupColl, groups => groups.Include(group => group.Title, group => group.Id));
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine("Groups Count: " + groupColl.Count);
                        foreach (Group grp in groupColl)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int grpId = grp.Id;

                                Console.WriteLine("SiteURL:  " + url);
                                Console.WriteLine("Group Name: " + grpName);
                                //For test purpose
                                Console.WriteLine(grp.Title);
                                if (grpName == grp.Title)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Match found"); 
                                    for (int i = 1; i < users1.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                        string temp = users1[i].Remove(0,8);
                                        Console.WriteLine(temp);
                                        **User user = web.EnsureUser(temp);**
                                        Console.WriteLine(user);
                                        addUsersToGroup(grpId, url, user);
                                    }
                                    break;  
                                } 

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                                drOutputError["Links"] = url;
                                drOutputError["Message"] = ex.Message.ToString();
                                dtErrors.Rows.Add(drOutputError);
                                drOutputError = dtErrors.NewRow();
                            }
                        }

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    drOutputError["Links"] = url;
                    drOutputError["Message"] = ex.Message.ToString();
                    dtErrors.Rows.Add(drOutputError);
                    drOutputError = dtErrors.NewRow();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            drOutputError["Links"] = url;
            drOutputError["Message"] = ex.Message.ToString();
            dtErrors.Rows.Add(drOutputError);
            drOutputError = dtErrors.NewRow();
        }

        ToCSVError(dtErrors, ",", true);
        Console.WriteLine("=======================Completed==================");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void addUsersToGroup(int grpId, string url,User user)
    {
        try
        {


            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                Group testingOwnersGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetById(grpId);
                clientContext.Load(testingOwnersGroup);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(testingOwnersGroup.Title);
                UserCollection collUser = testingOwnersGroup.Users;
                collUser.AddUser(user);
                clientContext.Load(collUser);
                clientContext.Load(testingOwnersGroup);
                **clientContext.ExecuteQuery();**

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static DataTable csvToDataTable(string file, bool isRowOneHeader)
    {

        DataTable csvDataTable = new DataTable();

        //no try/catch - add these in yourselfs or let exception happen
        String[] csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);

        //if no data in file ‘manually’ throw an exception
        if (csvData.Length == 0)
        {
            //  throw new Exception(CSV File Appears to be Empty”);
        }

        String[] headings = csvData[0].Split(',');
        int index = 0; //will be zero or one depending on isRowOneHeader

        if (isRowOneHeader) //if first record lists headers
        {
            index = 1; //so we won’t take headings as data

            //for each heading
            for (int i = 0; i < headings.Length; i++)
            {
                //replace spaces with underscores for column names
                headings[i] = headings[i].Replace(" ", "_");

                //add a column for each heading
                csvDataTable.Columns.Add(headings[i], typeof(string));
            }
        }
        else //if no headers just go for col1, col2 etc.
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < headings.Length; i++)
            {
                //create arbitary column names
                csvDataTable.Columns.Add("col" + (i + 1).ToString(), typeof(string));
            }
        }

        //populate the DataTable
        for (int i = index; i < csvData.Length; i++)
        {
            //create new rows
            DataRow row = csvDataTable.NewRow();

            for (int j = 0; j < headings.Length; j++)
            {
                //fill them
                row[j] = csvData[i].Split(',')[j];
            }

            //add rows to over DataTable
            csvDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        //return the CSV DataTable
        return csvDataTable;

    }
    static void ToCSVError(DataTable table, string delimiter, bool includeHeader)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (includeHeader)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                result.Append(column.ColumnName);
                result.Append(delimiter);
            }
            result.Remove(--result.Length, 0);
            result.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                if (item is System.DBNull)
                    result.Append(delimiter);
                else
                {
                    string itemAsString = item.ToString();
                    // Double up all embedded double quotes
                    itemAsString = itemAsString.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
                    // To keep things simple, always delimit with double-quotes
                    // so we don't have to determine in which cases they're necessary
                    // and which cases they're not.
                    itemAsString = "\"" + itemAsString + "\"";
                    result.Append(itemAsString + delimiter);
                }
            }
            result.Remove(--result.Length, 0);
            result.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ErrorLog"].ToString(), true))
        {
            writer.Write(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}